# Inserting axios result using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using *axios* to fetch from a `save.json` file through a *REST API*.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to return the result into the "tasks" in the top of my code. I am not sure where to put it in my code, and I am not sure what to write. I hope you have some recommendations or solutions.

This is my code to fetch:

```
export default function Tasks() {
  let [tasks, setTasks] = useState([

    {
      content: 'Example',
    }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/all',{
      crossDomain:true,
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      }
    )
    .then(function(res){
      console.log('TodoItems is fetching.. ',res);
      if (res.status !== 200){
        console.log('Fetching failed, response status: '+ res.status);
        return;
      }
      console.log(res.data.wordList)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' , err);
    });

  }, []);




 // });

  let handleAddTask = task => {
    setTasks(tasks.concat(task));
    console.log("handleAddTask content: " + JSON.stringify(task))
  };

  let handleDeleteTask = id => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };
```

This is what I receive:

```
TodoItems is fetching..  
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://localhost:8080/all", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data:
name: null
todo: null
wordList: Array(5)
0: {done: true, description: "Test"}
1: {done: true, description: "Test"}
2: {done: true, description: "Test"}
3: {done: true, description: "Test"}
4: {done: true, description: "Test"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
headers: {content-type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

My question is:

**How can I insert the wordList array into tasks, using the setTasks via hooks?**

The  `console.log(res.data.wordList)` returns:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
description: "Test"
done: true
__proto__: Object
1: {done: true, description: "Test"}
2: {done: true, description: "Test"}
3: {done: true, description: "Test"}
4: {done: true, description: "Test"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This is how the app looks like. I want to load my `save.json` into the app.

[image]

I am quite new to react, so excuse me if the question is stupid. I hope some of you would like to help out :)

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can set state in functional components using the second parameter of destructured array when using useState. In your case that would be setTasks..

```
 .then(function(res){
  console.log('TodoItems is fetching.. ',res);
  if (res.status !== 200){
    console.log('Fetching failed, response status: '+ res.status);
    return;
  }
  // set tasks here
  setTasks(res.data.wordList);

})
```

I suppose you want to trigger this effect only when mounting this component so leaving an empty array in the dependecies is ok (similar to componentDidMount), if not you might want to specify dependecies in you effect hook.

Comment: bare in mind this will override anything you initially set in tasks `{content: 'Example'}` if you want to keep that one and add the new ones you can do something like array concat - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Thank you very much! However - it displays empty elements. https://i.imgur.com/DdriUIe.png . @RossJohnson I am concating in another component - the one that is used for adding items to the list, so overriding is not a problem since I only want to load when the component is mounted:)

Comment: @ojbl that might be another issue, however if you console.log(tasks) and the tasks do contain your data then the fetching is successful.. maybe you can post your rendering jsx so we can resolve this

Comment: @ojbl check what property you're using as the name `content` vs `description`

Comment: @ojbl Also you would need to fix those error in the console as they can prevent rendering, also in the inital state you are using an object with property content while you are fetching data with property description where content is undefined, so as the above comment stated check if you are reading content or description prop

Comment: Thank you very much guys! `content`vs `description` was the issue in another component.

Comment: @ojbl Feel free to mark the answer if you found this helpful :)